# Fluid Height Constrained Images HTML

Tags: html, css

Looking for some assistance if its possible to do a fluid height image in CSS.

Ex) http://jsfiddle.net/VDB7A/20/

I want to have the box div at a set height, but dynamically size the container to show all the text at the bottom without going over the set box height. Basically this is for a fluid width site, where I want to cap the box height and auto adjust the image size to show all the text without going over the height.

Thanks!

Figured out my own answer:

I need to scale everything on width. So I need to put a min-width and max-width on the container. Then I need to put width:100% on the image. Height will always be auto.

http://jsfiddle.net/VDB7A/27/

Comment: If you solved your own problem, put the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: cant yet, i need to wait a few more hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to scale everything on width. So I need to put a min-width and max-width on the container. Then I need to put width:100% on the image. Height will always be auto.

http://jsfiddle.net/VDB7A/27/